# How to test a promise with delay in Jasmine 2.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a test case where I want to delay the promise in test case and reject if time exceeds 500 ms.

There is not $timeout used in actual service.

Anyidea how this can be acheived.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasmine 2.0 has support for asynchronous operations through the done() function. Use done as first parameter in your callback to it(). Also see [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).
You can then either call done() if your asynchronous operation has completed successfully or done.fail() on failure.

Assuming you have a function 'doSomething' that returns a Promise. And you want to ensure that the Promise fulfills within 500ms (otherwise the test should fail).
Then your test step could look like this (short version):

```
it("should return within 500ms", function(done) {
    doSomething().then(done, done.fail);
    setTimeout(function() { done.fail("doSomething took too long"); }, 500);
});
```

If you also want to check the result that is passed when the Promise fulfills then it could look like this:

```
it("should return within 500ms", function(done) {
    doSomething().then(function(result) {
        // check result here
        done();
    }, done.fail);

    setTimeout(function() { done.fail("doSomething took too long"); }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Any idea, why it may not work :
  entity2.isEmpty.and.returnValue($q.when(setTimeout(function () {
                    return true
                }, 600)));
I want to delay the return for the promise.

Comment: Checking in a Jasmine test whether some operation takes more than 500ms (and let the test fail then) makes sense to me. But why would you want to delay the return for a promise in a test ? That would only make the test slower. Could your provide more info or some code ? What does your Jasmine test look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setTimeOut function.
setTimeOut(*Your Promise resolution function*,500)